# How to display sidebar menu items visible by default in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Under sidebar i have created a menu as below and it displays the radiobutton on-click of the menu.

```
        sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem("Data Upload",tabName = "DataUpload", icon = icon("upload"),
                               radioButtons("radio", label = "Select input format",
                                            choices = list("Excel(xls/xlsx)" = 1, "CSV" = 2, "sql" = 3),selected = 1)
                                ))
```

But i need this to display by default and on-click of the menu it should hide the radiobuttion.